# What is the difference between "/" and "./"?

Tags: path

I'm not sure to really understant the fundamental difference between this two ways to access a path :

- "/"
- "./"

Can somebody help my to find it out ?

Answer (score 1):

the dot just refers to the current directory. but there are special meanings to some

1) . - current directory

2) .. - the directory before this current directory

3) ./somefolder - refers to a subfolder called  'somefolder' in this directory

4) ../hello - refers to a folder in a root directory with reference to ur current directory called 'hello'

Comment: OK, but what means only "/somefolder" ?

Comment: Because when you declare a servlet path you write "/servletPath"